# Shamir's Secret Sharing on non-prime GF

Tags: secret-sharing, finite-field

I am implementing Shamir's secret sharing scheme on arbitrary binary files.  I don't intend to use this; this is a project to help me explore cryptography.  In setting up the finite field arithmetic, I chose my field to be GF(257).

My understanding is that a prime GF is needed to ensure that a single modular inverse exists for each value in the field (this conflicts with the answer to [How can Shamir's method for secret sharing work in the GF(256)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/how-can-shamirs-method-for-secret-sharing-work-in-the-gf256)).

Can someone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: You may be misinterpreting the notation: $\mathrm{GF}(256)$ is **not** the ring of integers modulo $256$; it is the unique (up to isomorphism) degree-$8$ extension of $\mathrm{GF}(2)$. In particular, it *is* a field, while $\mathbb Z/256$ contains lots of zero divisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be confused by the sentence in the answer:

> If you use simple modular reduction they won't work (e.g. you can't just compute the operations *mod* 256).

This sentence is true, but doesn't mean what you think it does.

It doesn't mean that you can't compute inverses in $GF(256)$; instead, what it means is that you can't compute the addition and multiplication as $A + B \bmod 256$ and $A \times B \bmod 256$; other algorithms need to be used.

It happens that addition is easy; you can do it by doing a bitwise exclusive or; in C, that's `A ^ B`

Multiplication and inverses are a bit trickier; however, I can point you to the answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21173/how-to-calculate-aes-logarithm-table) that addresses how to do with with a few table lookups

Comment: that absolutely *would* compromise the security of the algorithm.  For example, if we had a scheme with threshold=2, and the attacker held the share at $x=1$, and he also know that there were participants with $x=2, 3, 4, 5$, even if he didn't know the values of the shares, he could exclude any secret value that would imply a value of 256 at any of those 4 $x$ coordinates.  As he doesn't hold threshold shares, he is not supposed to deduce anything about the secret.